# react-native-video-player not orienting when screen is rotated or full screen is clicked

Tags: react-native, react-native-video

I have the video displaying with the controls, but I can't get the video to become full screen in landscape when full screen is clicked or when the phone is rotated. I'm using react-native-video-controls which uses react-native-video as a dependency.

```
import React from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet, Dimensions, Text } from 'react-native';
import VideoPlayer from 'react-native-video-controls';
import OverlayButton from '../../../Images/overlay-button.svg';

const {width, height} = Dimensions.get("window");

const stylesCustom = StyleSheet.create({
    galleryContainer: {
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.1)'
    },
    header: {
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 50,
        zIndex: 100,
        width: '100%',
        paddingBottom: 10
    }
});

const VideoModal = (props) => {

return (
    <View style={[stylesCustom.galleryContainer]}>
        <View style={[stylesCustom.header]}>
            <View style={{ left: 20 }}>
                <OverlayButton onPress={() => props.handleCloseModal()}/>
            </View>
        </View>
        <View style={stylesCustom.image}>
            <VideoPlayer
                source={{ uri: `${props.streamingUrl}(format=m3u8-aapl)` }}
                control={true}
                paused={false}
                ignoreSilentSwitch="ignore"
                disableBack
                fullscreenOrientation="landscape"
                fullscreen="true"
            />
        </View>
    </View>
);
}

export default VideoModal;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first download dependencies react-native-orientation-locker
then

```
import Orientation from 'react-native-orientation-locker';
```

after that add below code

```
const [fullScreen, setFullScreen] = useState(false);
const FullScreen = () => {
        if(fullScreen){
            Orientation.lockToPortrait();
        } else{
            Orientation.lockToLandscape();
        }
        setFullScreen(!fullScreen)
    }
```

and in the return

```
<View style= {fullScreen ?  styles.fullscreenVideo : styles.video }>
                    <Video
                        fullscreen = {fullScreen}
                        ref={video}
                        source={{
                            uri:videos,
                            type:'mpd'
                        }}
                        style={{...StyleSheet.absoluteFill}}
                        
                    />
</View>
```

and Style

```
fullscreenVideo:{
        backgroundColor: 'black',
        ...StyleSheet.absoluteFill,
        elevation: 1,
                
    },
```

Answer (score 2):

you can be fixed horizontally when the screen is full.

you can use [react-native-orientation-locker](https://github.com/wonday/react-native-orientation-locker)

- Useage

```js
import Orientation from 'react-native-orientation-locker';
...
Orientation.lockToLandscape();
```

Answer (score 1):

try this for fullscreen with video controls and landscape:-

```
import React,{useRef,useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import { View ,StyleSheet,BackHandler,Dimensions,TouchableNativeFeedback,Text,StatusBar} from 'react-native';
import Video from 'react-native-video';
import Orientation from 'react-native-orientation';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
import Slider from '@react-native-community/slider';

let url=`http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4`;

const {width,height} = Dimensions.get("window");
 Icon.loadFont();
let overlayTimer;
let Timer;
const App = ({navigation}) => {
let  lastTap = null;
const [Fullscreen, setFullscreen] = useState(false);
const [paused, setpaused] = useState(false);
const [currentTime, setcurrentTime] = useState(0);
const [duration, setduration] = useState(0.1);
const [overlay, setoverlay] = useState(false);
const playerRef = useRef();

useEffect(() => {
    const backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener(
        "hardwareBackPress",
        backAction
      );
      return () => backHandler.remove();
}, [])

const backAction = () => {
    // navigation.goBack();
    return true;
  }

   const FullscreenToggle=()=>{
     
      if(Fullscreen){
         Orientation.lockToPortrait();
         StatusBar.setHidden(false)
         navigation.setOptions({headerShown: true});  
         setFullscreen(false)
      }else{
         Orientation.lockToLandscape();
         StatusBar.setHidden(true)
         navigation.setOptions({headerShown: false});
         setFullscreen(true);  
      }
     
    } 

   const  handleDoubleTap = (doubleTapCallback, singleTapCallback) => {
      const now = Date.now();
      const DOUBLE_PRESS_DELAY = 300;
      if (lastTap && (now - lastTap) < DOUBLE_PRESS_DELAY) {
        clearTimeout(Timer);
        doubleTapCallback();
      } else {
         lastTap = now;
        Timer = setTimeout(() => {
          singleTapCallback();
        }, DOUBLE_PRESS_DELAY);
      }
    }

   const  ShowHideOverlay = () => {
      handleDoubleTap(() => {
       }, () => {
          setoverlay(true)
          overlayTimer = setTimeout(() =>  setoverlay(false), 5000);
       })
    }
  const backward = () => {
      playerRef.current.seek(currentTime - 5);
      clearTimeout(overlayTimer);
      overlayTimer = setTimeout(() =>  setoverlay(false), 3000);
    }
    const  forward = () => {
      playerRef.current.seek(currentTime + 5);
      clearTimeout(overlayTimer);
      overlayTimer = setTimeout(() =>  setoverlay(false), 3000);
    }
  const onslide = (slide) => {
   playerRef.current.seek(slide * duration); 
   clearTimeout(overlayTimer);
   overlayTimer = setTimeout(() => setoverlay(false), 3000);
    }
    const  getTime = (t)=> {
      const digit = n => n < 10 ? `0${n}` : `${n}`;
      const sec = digit(Math.floor(t % 60));
      const min = digit(Math.floor((t / 60) % 60));
      const hr = digit(Math.floor((t / 3600) % 60));
      // return hr + ':' + min + ':' + sec; 
       return  min + ':' + sec; 
    }  
    const load = ({ duration }) =>setduration(duration);
    const progress = ({ currentTime }) =>setcurrentTime(currentTime);
  return <View style={styles.container}>
    <View style={Fullscreen ? styles.fullscreenVideo : styles.video}>
     <Video
source={{uri:url}}
style={{ ...StyleSheet.absoluteFill }}
ref={playerRef}
paused={paused} 
repeat={true}
onLoad={load}
onProgress={progress}
resizeMode={"cover"}
rate={1.0}
/>
    <View style={styles.overlay}>
      {overlay?
       <View style={{ ...styles.overlaySet, backgroundColor: '#0006',alignItems:'center',justifyContent:'space-around'}}>
          <View style={{width:50,height:50}}>
              <Icon name='replay-5' style={styles.icon} onPress={backward} />
          </View>
          <View style={{width:50,height:50}}>
             <Icon name={paused ? 'play-arrow' : 'pause'} style={styles.icon} onPress={() => setpaused(!paused)} />
          </View>
          <View style={{width:50,height:50}}>
             <Icon name='forward-5' style={styles.icon} onPress={forward} />
          </View>
            <View style={styles.sliderCont}>
                <View style={{...styles.timer,alignItems:'center'}}>
                   <View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
                    <Text style={{ color: 'white' }}>{getTime(currentTime)}/</Text>
                    <Text style={{ color: 'white' }}>{getTime(duration)}</Text>
                   </View>
                    <View style={{margin:5}}>
                    <Icon onPress={FullscreenToggle} 
                    name={Fullscreen ? 'fullscreen' : 'fullscreen-exit'}
                     style={{ fontSize: 20,color:'white' }} />
                    </View>
                </View>
                <Slider
                  style={{margin: 5}}
                  maximumTrackTintColor='white'
                  minimumTrackTintColor='white'
                  thumbTintColor='white'
                  value={currentTime / duration} 
                  onValueChange={onslide} 
                />
              </View>
        </View>
        :
        <View style={styles.overlaySet}>
                 <TouchableNativeFeedback onPress={ShowHideOverlay}><View style={{ flex: 1 }} /></TouchableNativeFeedback>
        </View>
      }
     </View>

   </View>

       {!Fullscreen&&
        <View style={{ flex: 1,backgroundColor:'white' }}>
            <Text>BitFrit Try Scroll View Here</Text>
        </View>
       }
     
     
 </View>
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   container: {
      flex: 1
    },
  video: { width, height: width * .6, backgroundColor: 'black' },
  fullscreenVideo: {
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFill,
      elevation: 1
  },
  overlay: {
   ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
 },
   overlaySet: {
   flex: 1,
   flexDirection: 'row',
   },
   icon: {
      color: 'white',
      flex: 1,
      textAlign: 'center',
      textAlignVertical: 'center',
      fontSize: 25
    },
    TextStyle:{
      fontSize: 20, textAlign: 'center',
      marginVertical: 100, color: '#6200ee', fontWeight: 'bold'
    },
    sliderCont: {
      position: 'absolute',
      left: 0,
      right: 0,
      bottom: 0
    },
    timer: {
      width: '100%',
      flexDirection: 'row',
      justifyContent: 'space-between',
      paddingHorizontal: 5
    },
   });
export default App;
```