How to Rotate or Change Video Orientation in React Native?
I'm facing an issue where I capture a video in my React Native app, and it's being recorded in landscape format by default. However, I need it to be saved in portrait format. How can I achieve this?
I haven't found a library specifically designed for this task. I've tried various libraries like react-native-video-processing in different versions, attempting to compress the video and swapping the height and width dimensions during compression in hopes of changing the orientation.
I haven't found a solution for it yet

Possible duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71227405/react-native-video-player-not-orienting-when-screen-is-rotated-or-full-screen-is
